# New http client incorrect Content-Type produces 415 errors

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've just updated Cake to 3.3 from 3.1 and seem to have broken some of my `http Clients`.

The problem seems to be on any request without a specific `Content-Type` set.

For example, I am performing this request:

`curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer kEnG562yz5bhE9igXf2YTcZ2bu0z" "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs"`

With the following `http Client`:

```
$http = new Client([
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token->token
    ]
]);

$response = $http->get('https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs');
```

This works fine on my staging server using `Cake\Network\Http\Client` but on my newly updated local server using `Cake\Http\Client` I get:

```
object(Cake\Http\Client\Response) {
    [protected] code => '415'
    [protected] reasonPhrase => 'Unsupported Media Type'
```

Where any requests with `Content-Type` seem to work without problem.

```
$http = new Client(['headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token->token
    ]
]);
```

Works fine on both servers.

I'm fairly sure it's the `Content-Type` stopping me, I've tried a few but I'm stabbing in the dark really.

Can anyone tell me the content type that was used by default by `Cake\Network\Http\Client` or what content type I should use to send such a simple request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it is a GET request there is no content-type required.

Prior to CakePHP 3.3 in ./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Network/Http/Client.php you can see the content-type is only set to a default ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded') where there is a string of data present, so in this case it would not have been set.

If it is working with application/json I'd use this to get rolling and check with autodesk to see what content-type the api is expecting on this request.

Comment: Cheers Simon I think you're right that it's not `Content-Type`, but It does not work with `application/json`. The call was fine before the update. Something has changed in the http Client that is breaking the request.